# AAB : Apk can't install after download from play store

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle

I have upload my .aab file to play store, then i go play store install the app, after that i install .apk file will get error .

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.xxx signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]

but my KEY AND PACKAGE NAME IS USING SAME WITH PLAY STORE!!!

Comment: This is because you are having the same Application installed on your device with the Debug Signing Key and now you are installing the app with Release Signing Key. That's why you are getting this error. First uninstall the Debug Apk from your device.

Comment: i don have install debug app on my device , i have build a release version and install to my phone and using same production key

Answer (score 1):

The "upload" key (eg. the release key from your local key-store) and the [Play App Signing](https://play.google.com/console/about/keymanagement) key (Google managed, when this feature had been enabled) are not necessarily the same. Therefore you must uninstall that package, before installing "the same" package with a different signature.

If you want to compare these two signatures by yourself, just unzip the packages, find the `META-INF/ANDROID_.RSA` and then run: `keytool -printcert -file ANDROID_.RSA` ...which will tell you the signature's fingerprint & algorithm.

Comment: How to make my apk sign same with play app signing?

even i build the aab file

bundletool build-apks --bundle=/app-appRelease-release.aab  --output=/app.apks --ks=/app.jks  --key-pass=pass:xxx --ks-key-alias=xxx --ks-pass=pass:xxx --mode universal

unzip the apks file then get the apk also get the same error

Answer (score 0):

My case using internal testing CH Play so I uninstall current version on device and install new Internal testing version on CH Play. It was installed successfully.